# I have a mysqli error in my library file {ERROR :: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given}

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have a mysqli error in my library file `ERROR :: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given` any one help me to solve it

My Installer file:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $CI = &get_instance();
        $CI->load->database();
        if ($CI->db->database == '') {
            header('location:install/');
        } else {
            //query from installer tbl
            $installer = mysqli_query('SELECT installer_flag FROM installer');
            $item = mysqli_fetch_assoc($installer);
            $flag = $item['installer_flag'];
            // if installer_flag = 0
            if ($flag == 0) {
                // make it 1
                mysqli_query('UPDATE installer SET installer_flag=1 WHERE id=1');
                if (is_dir('install')) {
                    header('location:install/success.php');
                }
            }
            //run this code
            //else nothing
        }
    }
```

Error: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given

Comment: mysqli_query expects two parameter one is connection object another one query

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli\_fetch\_array()/mysqli\_fetch\_assoc()/mysqli\_fetch\_row() expects parameter 1 to be resource or mysqli\_result, boolean given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysqli-fetch-array-mysqli-fetch-assoc-mysqli-fetch-row-expects-parameter-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using CI then use its inbuilt functions to get the result

```
$query = $this->db->query('SELECT installer_flag FROM installer');
foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
   echo $row['title'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** `mysqli_query` expects two parameter first parameter is `connection object` second parameter is `sql query`

**example :**

```
mysqli_query($connection_object,$query);
```

**Codeingniter :**

```
$result = $this->db->query('SELECT installer_flag FROM installer')->result();
print_r($result);
```